# C++ Boost Logging: how to zip logs?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-logging

I need to zip logs, produced by Boost Logging library. I see 2 approaches:

1. Compress logs on the fly to BZip or GZip - *preferably*
2. Compress logs when rotating (make copy of log and zip it).

How do I implement this?

Comment: how about man logrotate?

Comment: My program will run under WIN32, so I can't use logrotate. I also want to implement archivation in program, without using external stuff.

Comment: I think, what my question isn't obvious, so why you downvote? I'm trying to find out the most beautiful way. I could use cron or anything, but I want to implement it in my program.

Comment: Have you considered [Boost Iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) zlib or bzip filters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boost has [gzip filters](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/gzip.html), which could be [attached to a logging sink](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/sink_backends.html).